# Return an observable after two operations

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have two functions that return an `Observable` :

```
//get a new entity from server
public new(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>(api + 'New');
}

//create the entity
public create(data: any) {
  return this.http.post(api + 'Update', data);
}
```

Now, I need to write a function that calls these two functions and returns an `Observable` :

```
addNewItem(value: any): Observable<any> {
  this.service.new().subscribe(x => {
      // do something with "X" 
      return this.service.create(x);
  });
}
```

But, this does not work because `return` is inside `subscribe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you could use RxJS [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator. Try the following

```js
addNewItem(value: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.service.new().pipe(switchMap(x => {   // <-- note the `return` here
    // do something with "X" 
    return this.service.create(x);
  }));
}
```

**Why two return statements?**

The inner statement `return this.service.create(x);` denotes the observable to be switched to when handling the observable returned by `this.service.new()`.

The outer statement `return this.service.new()` denotes the observable to be returned by the function `addNewItem()`. In this case we switched it to the observable from `this.service.create(x)`.

One more thing to note about arrow functions:

```js
this.service.new().pipe(switchMap(x => this.service.create(x)));
```

is similar to

```js
this.service.new().pipe(switchMap(
  x => {
    return this.service.create(x);
  }
));
```

Essentially with the curly braces, the `return` statement must be explicitly stated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use switchMap from rxjs operators.

```
addNewItem(value: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.service.new().pipe(switchMap(x => this.service.create(x))
}
```

see the following link for more details:
[Angular4 - Nested Http Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45926836/angular4-nested-http-calls/45926900)