# Observable.catch() and exception handling in RxJs

Tags: angular, exception, rxjs

I am having a really hard time understanding RxJS and how to handle errors. I am using Angular (4+) and with their switch to RxJS for simple HTTP requests, I am finding myself having to wrestle really hard with something that seems trivial.

Here is my very contrived code:

```typescript
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import 'rxjs/add/observable/from';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title = 'app';
    index = 0;
    sub1: Subscription;
    fail = false;

    // the event generated by the user (click)
    eventA = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

    // another event, downstream from eventA
    eventB = this.eventA.mergeMap(x => this.fetchData(x));

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.sub1 = this.eventB.catch(err => {
            console.log(`error was caught!`);
            return this.eventB;
        }).subscribe(x => {
            this.title = x.toString();
        });
    }

    doIt() {
        this.eventA.next(Date.now());
    }

    fetchData(input: number) {
        if (this.fail) {
            return Observable.throw(new Error(`I failed!`));
        }
        return Observable.of(input);
    }
}
```

and the html:

```html
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="fail" (change)="fail = !fail" >Fail<br>
<button (click)="doIt()">doit()</button><br>
{{title}}
```

And here is the demo

[image: demo GIF]

As you can see, once it fails, the pipeline is not executed anymore. I can confirm that `eventA` is still good and so is `eventB`. However, it appears that `sub1` is unsubscribed.

That last part is what I don't understand. I am explicitly returning `eventB` so that it can continue... Or do I have this all wrong?

My use case is this:

- I have a business event (`eventA`) that forces data to be refreshed in the application.
- Instead of forcing all the components in the application to listen to that event and then *request* their new data, I want to leverage the power of Rx to simply have the data flow through the application.
- Therefore, my components subscribe to various *downstream* events
- The problem I have is that, like any data call, it can have errors. And I want each component to *handle* the error on its own.
- The downstream event can produce errors for those bad data calls, so **how do I let subscribers know of errors without killing the stream?**

Comment: The scenario needs more thought, but one thing I can say for sure is that an error notification ends the subscription. If you want to catch and continue subscribing, a `switchMap()` might work.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I did try `switchMap()` instead of `mergeMap()` but without any difference in the outcome. I understand that an error ends the subscription, but this seems to be a fairly trivial use case for RxJS.

Comment: I was thinking of switchMap where the catch is.

Comment: @RichardMatsen would you recommend separate _events_ or streams? one for success events and one for error events (related to the the same data)?

Comment: I'm setting up a testbed to see if it's viable - sorry I'm a bit vague on the pattern at the moment - just looking for a substitute for catch.

Comment: I don't fully grasp it yet but the solution here seems to work for your example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649652/rxjs-catch-error-and-continue I put it in a plnkr here http://plnkr.co/edit/u9vpCR8ltCwtsaTH0Cxl?p=preview

Comment: @HarryNinh thanks for the info. That was pretty much the first article that came up in my search for a solution. I did try to implement a variant of it but it sort of felt pretty heavy. I will take a look at your plnkr tomorrow. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Found this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LKMwkuK0ZE&t=1219s in the other thread, must watch! Now I understand the gist of `catch`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `.switchMap()` on the trigger observable to get a new fetch each click, and catching within the switchMap instead of after eventB.

`switchMap` effectively gives a new inner subscription each time, so if the old one closes because of an error, the next click it will start it again.

The only potential down side is that a fetch from 1st click is thrown away when another click happens before the fetch finishes.

```js
eventB = this.eventA.switchMap(x => {
  return this.fetchData(x)
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(`error was caught!`, err);
      return Observable.empty();
    })
});

...

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.sub1 = this.eventB
    .subscribe(x => {
        this.title = x.toString();
      }
    );
```

Here's the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4xphlc?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) I tested on.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am torn a bit because technically the events are in different services. But I think I can leverage this to generate 2 different events as I mentioned previously. This might actually make things cleaner.
Thanks for your help. I am warming up to RxJS, but it's quite a steep learning curve...

Comment: If by separate streams, you want to subscribe to errors separately you might need `onErrorResumeNext()` after the catch and `return Observable.of(err)` inside it (just some ideas to try).

Comment: So, I keep hearing and reading about this `onErrorResumeNext()`, but I can't find any documentation about it on the [RxJS website for Observable](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html)
Am I missing something?