# How do you handle recovery in the Angular Interceptor

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, interceptor

How can I recover an intercepted HTTP request in angular?

Here is an example of the catch and replace strategy with Observables

https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/

The goal is to catch the error, handle it and return a "success" observable to the original subscriber. I am not able to get this to work with Angular's interceptor.

This is dumbed down code but if I return an observable it does not hit the success of the original subscriber. It will hit its complete however. And the throwError works as expected.

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

return next
  .handle(req)
  .pipe(
    catchError((error, caught) => {
       return of('this does not work');
       //throwError('this works as expected');
    })
  );
```

}

Comment: possible duplicat of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38649652/rxjs-catch-error-and-continue

Comment: That link is the expected behavior. The question is why doesn't it work like that with angular's interceptor?

Comment: Please provide a working example of your problem. What you have here is correct but you're just saying it doesn't work.

Comment: if you're returning an observable of string it will not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

interceptor needs to return a `Observable<HttpEvent<any>>`

try:

```
 return of(new HttpResponse({ body: {} }));
```